# Need help to separate out file processing server

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, ocr

I have developed `Document Management System (DMS)` having `OCR` feature. However, it takes `too much time` to process, as well as `high CPU usage`.

My current process is synchronous, as below :

1. User upload his file
2. OCR process
3. Store document information in DB

Considering the real-time production load, I want to make above second step asynchronous, on a `dedicated file processing separate server`.

My questions are,

1. Is it the right way to do it?
2. How to send/retrieve that file to another server to process? I also found out to use message queue, but I can not add whole file in it.
3. Is there anyway, we can acknowledge process completion?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/233959/design-of-high-performance-file-processing-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, I have separated `OCR` process successfully on separate file processing server, which really helps me to resolve high CPU usage, using `FIFO` method.

Followed below steps :

1. User uploads file
2. OCR status pending
3. Separate server process file, which is pending as per FIFO method once at a time.
4. Update OCR process status in the database.

Processing server can be increased later, as per need and load of the server.